# Maven, break build on autovalue package usage

Tags: java, maven, auto-value

Autovalue includes a shadowed version of guava for the annotation processor stuff.  The problem is that autocomplete will often pull the autovalue guava version of a package in instead of the actual guava package.

What is the best way to prevent this from happening?  So far we have caught most of the problems, but I fear we may miss one.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this from happening by filtering out certain types from auto complete. For example, in Eclipse this can be done in Preferences under `Java -> Appearance -> Type Filters`

To avoid the problem with the shadowed version I added `*.shaded.*` as a type filter, this will filter out all types with at least one super package called `shaded`.

This feature is also useful if, for example, you use SWT and don't want to be bothered by autocompletion suggesting AWT/Swing types. For that I added `java.awt.*` and `java.swing.*` as type filters.